# How to bind a click listener not on an element in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I want to pop out a menu, and when the user click positions other than the menu, the menu will hide.
Also, if the click is on some nodes who have click listeners, those handling functions will not be triggered.
I can use a transparent mask layer to implement this, but is there any easier way (since I use jQuery)?
I tried the `:not` selector

```
$(document).on('click',':not(.menu)',function(e){
$('.menu').hide();
});
```

But it seems just not working (also should I add a `e.stopPropgation()` here)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would write something like this:

```
$(document).on('click', function(e){
  if($(e.target).parents(".menu").length == 0)
     $('.menu').hide();
});
```

Comment: Good suggestion. One more issue with this is that the menu is activated by a button. How can I organize the listeners so when pressing the button the menu could show? Now when I click the button, the menu won't show... ( I add a condition that $('.menu').css('display')!='none' in your if statement, but in console it shows the menu is already shown (display:block) when this listener is triggered so it is hidden again)

Comment: Well, if($(e.target).parents(".menu").length == 0 && $(e.target).parents(".trigger_btn").length == 0) could work... thanks again.

Comment: You are giving answers on your questions faster than me :) You're welcome.